# No Permissions for Jenkins user inside docker container

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I am trying to install maven into the docker linux container through a bash shell. I am using jenkinsci/blueocean image. I ran the following command to get the shell to run the commands to install maven:
    [image: missions for Jenkins us]

I am logged in as user jenkins but I do not have the permissions to run any commands. I tried running apt-get and sudo but it says "Permission Denied". I tried updating /etc/group/ but I got the same error. Here is the following commands I tried to make it work.

[image]

My main goal is to install maven and java so that I will be able to configure my jenkins. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to run the command as a root user.

```
docker exec --user root -it fad4ff7f84b4 ash
```

Second, [jenkinsci/blueocean](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/master/docker/official/Dockerfile) image is base on alpine, there is no `apt`, the package manager  for alpine is `apk`

so you can try

```
apk add --no-cache your_pacakge
#or
apk add --no-cache maven
```

Comment: Thanks @Adiii, It helped!